# Build fail Error with Omnet v5.7 and Veins 5.2

Tags: build, omnet++

Below is the debug console output from a Windows Omnet5.7, Veins5.2 project build - can anyone help how to fix these link and build errors . Something wrong in the makemake settings?

````
    \\\**** Incremental Build of configuration debug for project xxxx ****
    make MODE=debug all 
    cd src && /usr/bin/make
make[1]: Entering directory '/xxxx/src'
Creating executable: ../out/gcc-debug/src/xxxx_dbg.exe
lld-link: error: duplicate symbol: non-virtual thunk to inet::MobilityBase::getMaxSpeed() const
>>> defined at ../../inet4/src/inet/mobility/base/MobilityBase.h:181
>>>            ../out/gcc-debug/src/veins_inet/VeinsInetMobility.o
>>> defined at libINET_dbg.dll

lld-link: error: duplicate symbol: non-virtual thunk to inet::MobilityBase::getConstraintAreaMax() const
>>> defined at ../../inet4/src/inet/mobility/base/MobilityBase.h:183
>>>            ../out/gcc-debug/src/veins_inet/VeinsInetMobility.o
>>> defined at libINET_dbg.dll

lld-link: error: duplicate symbol: non-virtual thunk to inet::MobilityBase::getConstraintAreaMin() const
>>> defined at ../../inet4/src/inet/mobility/base/MobilityBase.h:184
>>>            ../out/gcc-debug/src/veins_inet/VeinsInetMobility.o
>>> defined at libINET_dbg.dll

lld-link: error: duplicate symbol: __NULL_IMPORT_DESCRIPTOR
>>> defined at libINET_dbg.dll.a(libINET_dbg.dll)
>>> defined at libveins_dbg.dll.a(libveins_dbg.dll)
collect2.exe: error: ld returned 1 exit status
make[1]: *** [Makefile:111: ../out/gcc-debug/src/xxxxx_dbg.exe] Error 1
make[1]: Leaving directory '/xxxx/src'
make: *** [Makefile:2: all] Error 2
"make MODE=debug all" terminated with exit code 2. Build might be incomplete.

21:09:59 Build Failed. 2 errors, 0 warnings. (took 1s.618ms)```
````

Answer (score 0):

I'd suggest, according to this page: https://veins.car2x.org/download/#compatibility
to use OMNeT++ version [6pre14](https://github.com/omnetpp/omnetpp/releases/download/omnetpp-6.0pre14/omnetpp-6.0pre14-windows-x86_64.zip) on Windows in order to get things working. I'm also using those versions, on Windows 11. All working*.

Comment: Thank you. Even with Omnet++ 6p15, Veins 5.2 has errors just building the source. Any workarounds ? Thanks again!

Comment: 14, I mentioned 14. https://github.com/omnetpp/omnetpp/releases/tag/omnetpp-6.0pre14 - download at the end of the page and let me know.

Comment: The download link to Omnet++ pre14 , redirects to pre15 install page .https://omnetpp.org/software/2021/11/15/omnet-6-pre14-released.html. Please have a look. Thank you for the link, I now installed Pre14 on Windows 10 - but INET library does not load properly ( missing java lib files ec ). it will be good to know the most stable combination of Omnet++, INET, Veins - combination that works . Thank you

Comment: You can click on 6pre14 in the main answer to start download automatically! Or https://github.com/omnetpp/omnetpp/releases/download/omnetpp-6.0pre14/omnetpp-6.0pre14-windows-x86_64.zip

Comment: Thank you , however , after several attempts  pre14 release just does not build on win10 .  I am stickin to a stable 5.6.2 version .

Comment: Sorry to hear that. I was pretty convinced it was due to a framework incompatibility. Since now the problem is the installation I think you might be missing some libraries, don't know the error you get...maybe for another question.